# Forcing project to load DLL's from the current directory

Tags: vb.net, dll, load, directory, project

I am trying to make a program that works on every operating system by forcing it to load and use the DLL's in the current directory, not the windows directory, but it don't works. I tried to enable "copy local" and change the refference path, but without any success, the program tries to load the DLL's from the windows directory.
My question is: how can I fix this?

Comment: Do you mean the windows directory, rather than e.g. the GAC? I.e. are these unmanaged DLLs?

Comment: I mean, how to make the program to use the DLL references in the current directory (debug)

Answer (score 2):

The Search Order for DLL's is [documented here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586.aspx). It also includes instructions on how you can modify the search order so that the local bin directory is searched first, instead of the GAC.

Answer (score 0):

The directory `%windir%\assembly` is called the [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache).  Assemblies are not copied there, but installed typically using `gacutil /i` or by installation packages.

GAC is a suitable folder for libraries referenced by lots of other libraries and applications in build versions that are not centrally coordinated.  Using GAC allows you to have multiple versions of the same library, all of which might be indirectly required even by a single application, installed side by side on the system.  Case in point is the .NET framework itself.

The assemblies that you build are probably not that kind.  Application assemblies and libraries that are basically part of a single application should never make it to the GAC or you can get into trouble.  There is a variety of possible trouble:

- one accidentally or intentionally creates different (incompatible) builds of the same library with the same version number.
- assembly in GAC references an assembly not in GAC
- one app installs the same assembly into GAC, but another app wants to load it from its local folder (where application binaries reside).

Code in the GAC gets a preference when assemblies are loaded.  To remove an assembly from the GAC, use `gacutil /u`.